# Why are buttons "Settings" in top navigation bar in a list app missing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have several list apps in my SharePoint 2013 Teamsite.

In some of them are the  buttons `Settings` in top navigation bar in a list app missing. In the other very similar list apps the `Settings` Buttons are visible.

How can I enable and use the missing ones?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this area is fairly well known to have difficulties and given the lack of information I've had to put a number of things here for you to try. It's likely isolated to Internet Explorer 9.x, so you if you need to get there quickly I'd suggest doing so in Chrome.

A few things that I've known to try in this case:

- Check that your browser it not zoomed in at all. Set your zoom back to 100%. Often when you're at 125% zoom you won't see all of the ribbon elements.
- Try clearing cache and reloading the page.
- If neither of these have worked you likely have a content accelerator running and will need to look into disabling, or refining it.
- If you've been editing the pages for your list then [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44492/list-ribbon-button-disappeared) will provide further information for you.